# Baked normal map creates seams on export to glTF

Tags: normals, baking, gltf, seams

I'm trying to create a model for a threeJS application, but the resulting glb file shows always more or less noticable seams, depending how the light hits the modell.
I was told that I might bake the map incorrectly or some other setting in blender is incorrect but I don't know what:

The Color Space is set to Non-Color.
The Image uses 32-bit float.
I use Tangent Space for baking and using the Normal Map node with the Tangent Space option.
I ticked following export options: UV's, Normals, Tangents, Vertex Colors.

And I'm still getting visible seams... A higher resolution normal map makes the seam appear clearer since the surface appears to be less "noisy".
In Blender the seams doesn't appear to be visible no matter how high I set the normal map strength.

Is there anything else to consider?

Here a picture:

[image]

Comment: One thing to consider it that glTF only supports one tangent map per mesh. So if your materials use more that 1 UV map the tangents that they use might me incorrect for the tangent space normal maps. The glTF exporter exports tangents only for the active render UV map.

Comment: It might also be worth trying this file in a couple viewers (like https://sandbox.babylonjs.com/ and https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/) to see if it might be a viewer bug.

Comment: @unwave I just use a single image as a normal map. It is connected to the "Normal" input at the Principled BSDF node with a "Normal Map" Node in between.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy Yeah, I've tried these and I can't see any seams. Could be the light though. My screenshot above shows that the seam might be not visible depending on illumination.

Comment: How many UV maps exist on your Blender mesh?

Comment: @DonMcCurdy I'm using only one single UV map. At least the Object Data Properties show only one "UVMap".

Comment: "image uses 32-bit float" -- this might be a clue actually, is it an OpenEXR file? Could you try converting to PNG? There was a similar issue in older versions of Blender: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/issues/1473

Comment: @DonMcCurdy After baking I saved the normal map as PNG and Base Color, Roughness and Emission as JPG. I never used EXR.
If it helps, I could share my blend and glb, if you want.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy Here is the link to the glb file: https://we.tl/t-WNY9JNsdyO
Maybe you are able to confirm if there is a general problem within the file or if it comes from the exporter like mentioned in the github issue.

Comment: I've tried this model in three different viewers based on three different engines, including three.js, rotating the lighting and all of that — can't find a seam anywhere. I suspect this is not a problem of the model, but something about your app's setup. It might be best to post code and details including the three.js version on https://discourse.threejs.org/ for a deeper investigation.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy Yeah, that's what I already did and then I got told to ask here.
You think that I should try there again?
Well, I've updated ThreeJS and tried to recreate the problem with a minimal setup. I noticed, that the seam gets visible whenever the bright light spot gets near.

Comment: If you have an existing question in the three.js forums i guess you could bump that or link to it. But generally it's very hard for others to help if they can't reproduce the issue on their own computer. So it's less about where the question is, and more about including *all* necessary context to reproduce the error quickly, which can be easier in a forum thread than a SO question.